# Forcing integrated terminal to scroll down after relayed command

Tags: buffers, terminal, vim-windows, window-management

I have a plugin which integrates a terminal that I can send commands through using a custom command I made. The only issue I'm having is that sometimes after the terminal gets clogged, it tends not to scroll to the latest input, forcing me to constantly switch to it and manually `G`.

Since in my setup I already have the buffer & window ID, I thought I could add extend my custom command to switch to the terminal, `G`, and switch back, after the command had been sent. Thing is, I haven't found any way to switch to another window solely by using its ID. How can this be done?

Alternatively, is there a way to send `G` straight to a window? That way I won't have to jump between them.

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/29510/10604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the window ID then [`win_execute({winid}, {command})`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#win_execute()) should be useful. It is like `execute()` but operates in the context of the specified window.

Something like:

```
:call win_execute({winid}, '$')
```

`$` is the EX command equivalent of the Normal mode command `G`, i.e. move the cursor to the end of the buffer.

Give that a try.

---

Oh, ran a little test and noticed a bit of a hiccup. The movement was registered but didn't display until I moved the cursor there. A workaround, if you need it, is to send a screen redraw command to the window after the movement command. For example, this worked for me...

```
:call win_execute({winid}, 'norm <c-l>')
```

You might be able to combine the two `win_execute()` commands into one by putting a pipe character (`|`) between the two EX commands in the string parameter. Something like...

```
:call win_execute({winid}, '$ | norm <c-l>')
```

But if you're interested in this you'll have to test it as I haven't tried it, yet.

And see [`:h :norm`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#:norm) and [`:h CTRL-L`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#CTRL-L), if you're unfamiliar with the mentioned EX commands.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Worked for me even without refreshing. Is there a similar command for Neovim?

Comment: Cool. Not sure about nvim. Certainly not the same func. I quickly guessed at some things and found this: `nvim_win_set_cursor({window}, {pos})`. First param is called window "handle" in docs but I imagine it's the same thing as win id. That might do it. Or it could be equivalent to vim win number. It'll probably be pretty clear with some poking around in the help. If you get stuck go ahead and ask a new question.

Comment: I ended up just jumping to the window, running the command, and then jumping back using `wincmd w` for nvim.

Comment: But how can you stand the inconsistency of methods across the two? ;)

Comment: This question seems related, and there are links there that are also related. If they are dupes, we should link them together; otherwise, perhaps you have answers? :) LMK what you think re: dupes https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/29510/10604

Comment: They certain look related after a quick scan. What's your proposed course of action? (note: I will be unavailable for the next 4-5 hours).